# What we observe in neutrino experiments?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos

Apart from  the survival and transition probabilities, are there any other measurable quantities in  a  neutrino oscillation experiment?

Comment: Upper limits for mass, lower limits for speed would leap to mind.

Comment: We use at least four techniques to observe neutrinos; each has different characteristics, and much can be deduced through clever analysis. Some previous questions where the answers hold part of the answer(s) include: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87565, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/245963, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201654, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26507, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153836, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70137, and probably others.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [at this review](http://www-archive.ph.ed.ac.uk/sussp61/lectures/06_McFarland_NeutrinoInteractions/Lecutre%20Notes%20for%20Web/Web%20SUSSP%20Neutrino%20Interactions%20Lecture%20Two.pdf) of what neutrino antineutrino scattering experiments have taught us. They were crucial in supporting the quark model against the parton model back in the 1970's.

> •  Charged - Current:  W± exchange
>
> Quasi-elastic Scattering:
>
> (Target changes but no break up) νμ + n → μ− + p
>
> •      Nuclear Resonance Production:
>
> (Target goes to excited state) νμ + n → μ− + p + π0 (N* or Δ) n + π+
>
> •Deep-Inelastic Scattering:
>
> (Nucleon broken up)
>
> •  Neutral - Current:  Z0 exchange
>
> Elastic Scattering:
>
> (Target unchanged) νμ + N → νμ + N
>
> • Nuclear Resonance Production: (Target goes to excited state) νμ + N → νμ 
>   + N + π   (N* or Δ)
>
> • Deep-Inelastic Scattering
>
> (Nucleon broken up)